# W2K8 R2 Server session from OSX RDP client poorly renders text in MS Access 16

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mac-osx, rdp, microsoft-access

Windows Server 2008 R2 which is used primarily to run MS Access for browsing and manipulating various databases.

*OS Name Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OSX Remote Desktop v8 and 10.3
MS Access 16.0.12026.20194*

The problem happens on the right 33% of the display, but once it's garbled moving the application window to the left doesn't fix it, it stays garbled.
[image: Screenshot]

Update: The problem appears to be related to Microsoft's RDP client for MacOS. We installed the iTeleport and all works fine.

Comment: *Update:* the same server with the Remmina RDP client from an Ubuntu desktop displays the text correctly.  Windows 10 clients also don't have this problem, so this seems to be limited to the Mac client.

Answer (score 0):

The fix from MS may never be forthcoming since few people use 2560 x 1440 monitors for remote desktops to W2k8R2 servers.  So installing a 2rd party client is the best way forward.